# Delete specific div

Tags: jquery, html, css, content-management-system

I want to delete a specific `div` inside a `div` using jQuery. How can I do it? Here is my code:

```
echo "<div class=\"da-slide\">
    <h2>".$OPST."</h2>
    <p>".$OPSC."
    </p>
    <div class=\"da-img\">
    <input onclick='SLIDE_EDIT($OPID);' class=\"slideedit\" type=\"button\" value=\"EDIT\"> 
    <input onclick='SLIDE_DELETE($OPID);' class=\"slidelete\" type=\"button\" value=\"DELETE\" > 
    <input id=\"$OPID\" onclick='SLIDE_HIDE($OPID);' class=\"slidehide\" type=\"button\" value=\"$OPSS\" > 

    ".$OPSI."  
    </div>
```

This is my delete script. What i did i just to refresh the page after.

```
function SLIDE_DELETE(SLIDEID)
{
    $.post('insert_home.php',{
    SLIDE_DELETE:SLIDEID}).done(function(data){
    alert('SLIDE SUCCESSFULLY DELETED');
    location.reload();
    });
}
```

Comment: why using AJAX to delete elements ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always better to use jQuery event handlers.

Since you have an inline event handler, pass the clicked element reference to the delete function so that it can be deleted

```
<input onclick='SLIDE_DELETE($OPID, this);' class=\"slidelete\" type=\"button\" value=\"DELETE\" >
```

then

```
function SLIDE_DELETE(SLIDEID, el) {
    $.post('insert_home.php', {
        SLIDE_DELETE: SLIDEID
    }).done(function (data) {
        alert('SLIDE SUCCESSFULLY DELETED');
        //you may want to delete the da-slide element which contains the delete button
        $(el).closest('.da-slide').remove();
        //if you just want to remove the delete button
        //$(el).remove()
    });
}
```